# Probability question using Bayes Theorem

Tags: probability, bayesian, bayes-theorem

Hello Everyone I am having trouble understanding how to use bayes theorem in this problem:

Suppose a physician assesses the probability of
HIV in a patient who engages in risky behavior (unprotected sex with multiple partners
of either sex, or sharing injection drug needles) as .002, and the probability of HIV in a
patient who does not engage in those risky behaviors as .0001. Also suppose the Elisa
test has a sensitivity (probability of having a positive reading if the patient has HIV)
of .99, and a specicity (probability of having a negative reading if the patient does
not have HIV) of .99 and does not depend on whether the patient has engaged in risky
behavior. Let E stand for engages in risky behavior," H stand for has HIV," and R
stand for positive Elisa result." Use Bayes Theorem to compute each of the following:

(a) P(H|E,R), (b)...Ill solve this on my own...

How do I use the theorem for a?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\Pr(H\mid E, R) =& \frac{\Pr(H, E, R)}{\Pr(E,R)}\\
=& \frac{\Pr(H, E, R)}{\Pr\left(H,E,R\right) + \Pr(\overline H,E,R)}\\
=& \frac{\Pr(R\mid H,E)\Pr(H,E)}{\Pr(R\mid H, E)\Pr(H,E) + \Pr(R\mid\overline H,E)\Pr(\overline H,E)}\\
=& \frac{\Pr(R\mid H,E)\Pr(H\mid E)\Pr(E)}{\Pr(R\mid H, E)\Pr(H\mid E)\Pr(E) + \Pr(R\mid\overline H,E)\Pr(\overline H\mid E)\Pr(E)}\\
=& \frac{\Pr(R\mid H)\Pr(H\mid E)}{\Pr(R\mid H)\Pr(H\mid E) + \Pr(R\mid\overline H)\Pr(\overline H\mid E)}\\
\end{align}$$

and it's your turn to substitute appropriate numbers in this formula.

If you practice much, actually you can solve this kind of question solely using definitions and formulae.

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't figure out how to expand bayes from P(A|B) to P(A|B,C)